# Do we need [drag] and [drop] when we can use [drag-and-drop]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I see no reason to have separate [drag](/questions/tagged/drag) (1100+) and [drop](/questions/tagged/drop) (600+) tags when we can make use of [drag-and-drop](/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop) (5000+). [drop](/questions/tagged/drop) is also used for SQL questions, but I think those should be renamed to something like [sql-drop](/questions/tagged/sql-drop).

Answer (score 7):

I added [sql-drop](/questions/tagged/sql-drop) tag and retagged a few questions.

I also think that instead of [drag](/questions/tagged/drag) and [drop](/questions/tagged/drop) **,** [drag-and-drop](/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The [drop](/questions/tagged/drop) tag has been re-tagged or removed from all questions. The [drag](/questions/tagged/drag) tag still exists but is not particularly useful.